# py2exe + pywin32 MemoryLoadLibrary import fail when bundle_files=1

Tags: python, py2exe, pywin32

I have created a simple program which uses pywin32. I want to deploy it as an executable, so I py2exe'd it. I also didn't want a huge amount of files, so I set `bundle_files` to 1 (meaning bundle everything together). However, when I attempt running it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pshelper.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "win32.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading win32ui.pyd
```

In my setup script, I tried doing `packages=["win32ui"]` and `includes=["win32ui"]` as options, but that didn't help. How can I get py2exe to include win32ui.pyd?

I don't have this problem if I don't ask it to bundle the files, so I can do that, for now, but I'd like to know how to get it to work properly.

Comment: Note that doing `'dll_excludes': [ "mswsock.dll", "powrprof.dll" ]`, as suggested in some other answers, doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-around that has worked best so far is to simply re-implement the pywin32 functions using ctypes. That doesn't require another .pyd or .dll file so the issue is obviated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the problem is that win32ui.pyd is not included?  The stack trace isn't exactly the same as noted in the wiki, but check this out: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32ui.

Comment: i think that's the case because I get the DLL load error when i don't try to bundle the files. this just seems to be an issue w/ bundling.

Comment: py2exe won't bundle external DLLs into the archive or executable.  Try slurping the MFC files into the directory containing the exe and see if it runs.
As a side note - if you don't have zipfile = None, then you can unzip the archive to see whether or not your suspicions of win32ui.pyd not being bundled are warranted.

Comment: .pyd files aren't external DLL files, though. It seems to include them in the exe file, but they aren't loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do care to try out [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/d3398dd79b68901ae1edd761f3fe0f4ff19cfb1a/project/doc/Manual.html)? I've used it both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked like magic, even when I compiled to .pyd on Windows.

I've been able to bundle all sorts of applications that I've developed with it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem trying to bundle psutil with py2exe. Here is what I found so far.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wx_gui.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "psutil\__init__.pyc", line 85, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "psutil\_psmswindows.pyc", line 15, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading _psutil_mswindows.pyd
```

I get this traceback when bundle_files = 3. zipfile may be specified or may be None, I still get the problem.

First, I thought this was a missing dll because of this page:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ProblemsToBeFixed

I've copied all the dlls I found in Python27 into the same directory as the executable and added that directory path to os.environ['path']. That didn't worked.

Then I tried to import my package directly from site-packages.

I've replaced the whole sys.path of my compiled executable with my normal sys.path

sys.path = [r'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib', ...]

I think the .pyd module got imported but Visual c++ threw me this really ugly error message:

```
Runtime Error!
Program: {path}.exe
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I suggest you try to replace the whole sys.path to see if it is working. If it is, you could always make your single executable **write the necessary module into a temp directory** and add it to your path. If not, I feel like this problem is going to be hard to solve.